# Writing an ics file that will work on Android and Apple phones, but knowing that the timezone will change before the events happen

Tags: android, ios, datetime, icalendar

I've created an ics file that lists performances of a Xmas show that I will be working on, along with a team of about 50 others. I've created it today (when the UK is on British Summer Time), but the dates are all in December and January (when the UK will be back on GMT).  I've done a fair bit of research on what to include in the ics file to make sure the timezone change will not be an issue, but I obviously won't be able to test this until after October 30th (the date the UK goes to GMT).  All the users of this calendar will be in the UK, and I plan to share it by uploading the ics file to dropbox, so I WON'T be sharing it via URL.  For that reason I've avoided specifying times in UTC (with the 'z' suffix), as some users will be on Android phones, others will want it on their iPhones.

I've used the VTIMEZONE declaration at the start (I don't really understand all the variables but I found a Europe/London version somewhere and copy/pasted it), and also the X-WR-TIMEZONE variable (although I've read somewhere that these two shouldn't co-exist).  To be safe, I've also added the TimezoneID (TZID) to every start date and end date in each VEVENT.

I would be grateful if someone with expertise in this field could have a look through the opening of my code and let me know if the event times will be correct (ie as they are now) when the clocks change in the UK.  It will be too late to distribute it after the clock change (October 30th).

The beginning of my ics file looks like this.....

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CSV to iCal Convertor//Manas Tungare, manas.tungare.name//EN
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:Panto Dates
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/London
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETTO:-0000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T010000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZOFFSETFROM:-0000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE

X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London

BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:T1 (Tech)
DESCRIPTION:
DTSTAMP:20161203T100000
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20161203T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20161203T200000
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
*(......more events.....)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK, except for the DTSTARTs in the VTIMEZONE components. I'm not an expert in english timezone history but Daylight Saving was probably not established in 1601...
That said, a lot of clients just ignore the timezone definition and just rely on the TZID if it is present and known to them.

In any case, something like the following might work better:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
DTSTART:19961027T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:GMT
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19960331T010000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:BST
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```